# Which font-face format to include in email?

Tags: email

I'm trying to use a custom font in my email by importing it in my css like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova';
  src: url('myCDN/proxima-nova-regular.eot');
  src: url('myCDN/proxima-nova-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('myCDN/proxima-nova-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('myCDN/proxima-nova-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('myCDN/proxima-nova-regular.svg#ywftsvg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

However, I'm worried that if I import all those formats then my email will get bloated. Is there a standard format that I should be using or is it ok to import all of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can safely omit svg, eot, woff since most email clients do not use them.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/eot/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/svg/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/woff/

In addition, I find I can meet most font needs using `<link>`. It might be worth considering for your own needs. Just remember to have a good fallback websafe fonts, since Outlook, Gmail and several other popular email clients still do not work with web fonts.

Good luck.

Comment: In this article it says `woff` is `considered to be the most widely supported of font formats for email` https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/02/10-things-need-know-web-fonts-email-right-now/?

Comment: You can compare the support for eot, svg and woff and if you find all of the same clients support eot, woff and True Type, you could always remove a duplicate and focus on what best supports your customers.